# influxdb - filter tag by regex

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm trying to filter with a list made before like:

With version InfluxDB v2.6.0

[image: source value]

```
    ldevname = from(bucket: v.bucket)
     |> range(start: -365d)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "LDEV_CNF" )
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r.poolid == "${pool}")
      |> keep(columns: ["_value","poolid"])
      |> group()
      |> keep(columns: ["_value"])

ldevname
```

the output:

[image: output]

Then the main query as an error:

invalid: compilation failed: error @17:37-17:50: regex parse error: ${ldevname} error: repetition quantifier expects a valid decimal

```
ldevname = from(bucket: v.bucket)
 |> range(start: -365d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "LDEV_CNF" )
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.poolid == "${pool}")
  |> keep(columns: ["_value","poolid"])
  |> group()
  |> keep(columns: ["_value"])
  
//ldevname

from(bucket: v.bucket)
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "LDEV" and r._field == "LDEV_IOPS" )
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["ldevID"] =~ /${ldevname}/ )
// an others try without success:
//|> filter(fn: (r) => r["ldevID"] =~ (v: /^$ldevname$/) )
//|> filter(fn: (r) => r["ldevID"] =~ /^$ldevname$/ )
```

Many thanks for any help